# How to call function of class viewmodel inside it

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I get an error in my export class, `"AlertMessageIsRead is not a function"`

here is my code:

```
class MainViewModel {
    ClickAlertMessage() {
        var currentRecord = this;
        if (currentRecord != null) {
            this.AlertMessageIsRead(currentRecord);
        }
    }

    AlertMessageIsRead(record) {

        var pagename = '';

        AlertMessageService.Factory().IsReadAlertMessage(record.RecordId).then(response => {
            if (response.Result != null) {
                if (this.EntityLookupName == 'ProductStockLimitReached') {
                    pagename = '#product?Id' + '=' + this.RecordId;
                }
                else if (this.EntityLookupName == 'DRDueDateReached') {
                    pagename = '#delivery-receipt?Id' + '=' + this.RecordId;
                }
                this.RedirectPage(pagename);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

how can I call my `AlertMessageIsRead`?
other of my functions, I'm calling like `this.myfunction` but here, my `this` has a value.

Comment: cant you just use `MainViewModel.AlertMessageIsRead(x)` ? if not assign to a var before applybinding like `var vm = new MainViewModel(); ko.applyBindigs(vm)` then you can access with `vm.AlertMessageIsRead(x)`

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see the actual HTML to be 100% positive about the answer, but I have the feeling it is because `this` is not the context you think it is.
Instead of calling your function like  this:
`data-bind="click: ClickAlertMessage"`
try it like this:
`data-bind="click: () => ClickAlertMessage()"`

Arrow functions always pass parent context.

P.S. Try looking at the context `console.log(this)`